# Linux System V IPC: Unable to initialize semaphore value

Tags: c, linux, ipc, semaphore, sysv-ipc

I have created a simple semaphore initialization example for demo purpose:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int init_semaphore(int semid, int semnum, int initval)
{
    union semun pack;
    pack.val = initval;
    return semctl(semid,semnum,SETVAL,pack);
}
```

But I am getting the error:

```
error: aggregate ‘init_semaphore(int, int, int)::semun pack’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

I am not able to understand why the compiler is throwing the error. The headers are also included properly.

Comment: `man semctl`: *[...]When there are four, the fourth has the type union semun.  The  calling  program  must define this union as follows:

           union semun {
               int              val;    /* Value for SETVAL */
               struct semid_ds *buf;    /* Buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET */
               unsigned short  *array;  /* Array for GETALL, SETALL */
               struct seminfo  *__buf;  /* Buffer for IPC_INFO
                                           (Linux-specific) */
           };*

Comment: @EOF - that's an answer, not a comment (and now AndrewHenle has it as an answer)

Answer (score 4):

You have to explicitly declare `union semun` yourself.

Per the [POSIX standard for `semctl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semctl.html):

> The semctl() function provides a variety of semaphore control
>   operations as specified by cmd. The fourth argument is optional and
>   depends upon the operation requested. If required, it is of type
>   `union semun`, **which the application shall explicitly declare**:
>
> ```
> union semun {
>     int val;
>     struct semid_ds *buf;
>     unsigned short  *array;
> } arg;
> ```

Per the [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semctl.2.html):

> This function has three or four arguments, depending on `cmd`.  When
>          there are four, the fourth has the type `union semun`.  The calling
>          *program* must define this union as follows:
>
> ```
>    union semun {
>        int              val;    /* Value for SETVAL */
>        struct semid_ds *buf;    /* Buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET */
>        unsigned short  *array;  /* Array for GETALL, SETALL */
>        struct seminfo  *__buf;  /* Buffer for IPC_INFO
>                                    (Linux-specific) */
>    };
> ```

Comment: Do you know what the rationale is for making the program declare `union semun`, rather than simply having it declared in a standard header like `<sys/sem.h>`?

Comment: @NateEldredge The only reason I can think of is that by the time the call was standardized, too much legacy code would have been broken.